# how to create alert where automatically link name should be shown in an alert box?

Tags: javascript

I have created alert messages by clicking on the hyperlink. when I have clicked on a link, that message should open as a link name and it should not be in hard code. 
How can I create the message as link name in the alert box?

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" onclick="alertIt()">click me</a>



function alertIt(){
          //here I want link name message.
            alert("message");

    }
```

Comment: I see you've updated your question but can you please clarify what you mean by "link name"? Do you want the text content inside the `a` tag to be displayed in the alert?

Comment: I want to print link name for example here my link name is "click me".

Comment: I've updated my answer again, it now alerts the link name.

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to your alert function inside the `href` attribute.

```js
function alertIt(event) {
  alert(event.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" onclick="alertIt(event)">click me</a>
```

Comment: thanks, but if I want to print link name in an alert box then?

Comment: @AartiGoswami I've updated my answer, you can pass an argument to the function and let it display any message you like, including the link's name.

Comment: But my requirement is that a link name in the alert message should not be in hard code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
alert(`You are going to ${e.target.href}`);
});
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">click me 1</a>
```